# R twitteR 'created' column timezone

Tags: r, twitter

I am using R twitteR package and I wonder which timezone, **local or UTC**, have the tweets read by **searchTwitter** method. Afterwards I am converting them to a dataframe using **twListToDF**.

The format obtained is as this one: "2015-09-18 23:59:41".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

UTC +0

I believe see below for confirmation that the created_at field within Twitter Search API is UTC +0. This leads me to believe that the created field within the twitteR package returns that same value.

https://dev.twitter.com/tags/finding-tweets